# Python-Twitter script works at home and not at University. Deadline REALLY soon

Tags: python, twitter, urllib2, raspberry-pi

I've written quite a simple python script that pulls in tweets and turns on a GPIO if a filter is matched. I've tried it at home and it works really well, however, on the University network it seems not to be able to connect to twitter.

The details of the University network are
WIRELESS
SSID: Uni-WiFi
WPA2 Enterprise

It uses PEAP (MSCHAPv2) to connect, meaning that I need to type in my university username and password.
The network is connected at present and I can browse the internet, but when I launch the python script I get the error:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Here is the full python script - If any body could help it would be amazing, this needs handing in really soon!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import twitter
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library
import time ## Import 'time' library. Allows us to use 'sleep'
from termcolor import colored

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.cleanup()

#My app keys and secrets
CONSUMER_KEY = 'TXXGPRg'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'jRVxtEgf1CQWuan0N8L4a3s'
OAUTH_TOKEN = '528854Jaudhna2K36g4y79oiwUq'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'ZoQEv1deAQ'

FILTER_TAG = u'art'  # Can also be just text, like u'idol', but expect a lot more results!

# We want a continuous stream of events which match a given tag, so we need to use the streaming API.
twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=twitter.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET))

# Now, we don't want every single tweet from the stream, so we'll filter to include only specific text, or a specific tag.
iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track = FILTER_TAG)

# Now, iterator is a generator which yields a new tweet whenever it sees one. We need to loop over it forever.
for tweet in iterator:

        print colored(tweet.get(u'user', {}).get(u'name'), 'white', 'on_red'), colored(tweet.get(u'text'), 'cyan')

        if "hate" in tweet.get(u'text', u'fake_text_that_never_matches'):  # Now, you need to light up the light for 5 seconds, then shut it off.
            print colored("Switch turned ON!", "red", 'on_yellow')
            GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(7,True)## Switch on pin 7
            time.sleep(5)## Wait
            GPIO.output(7,False)## Switch off pin 7

        print "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy in your university? [I would also obfuscate your keys]

Comment: I'm not sure its a proxy as such. It uses PEAP (MSCHAPv2) (?????)
I've deleted some characters from those keys.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the OAuth signature is a timestamp, which is generated when you make the request. If your server's time differs too much from Twitter's server time, the Twitter server will reject your request with a 401. So, check the time being returned by the Twitter server and make sure your local machine that is generating the signature matches the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using a Raspberry Pi for this and the time is not set to the actual time. Do I just change the time under options for the Raspberry Pi? - I didnt need to do this on my home network.
Thanks again!